# Make next tabs active after some delay using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have list of tabs, on page load first is active. but what I want is after some delay i want make second tab active and again third tab etc. how to achieve this please some one help me.

Below is code,

```
<ul class="list-style-none project-menu owl-carousel-picker owl-theme">
                                    <!-- <ul class="list-style-none project-menu owl-carousel owl-theme"> -->


                                     <!--    <h3 class="col-hidden-sm col-visible-xs">Pick Selector :</h3> -->
                                        <!-- <span id="pick-selector">Pick Selector :</span> -->
                                        <li class="active">
                                            <a class="active" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                                                <div class="project-icon"><i class="retail-hm"></i></div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                                                <div class="project-icon"><i class="flaticon-transport"></i></div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                                                <div class="project-icon"><i class="bank-hm"></i></div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
```

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: @Zenoo actuaaly i dono go with this can you help me on this

Comment: Sounds like `setTimeout` is your friend

Comment: @aletzo More like `setInterval`.

Comment: Yep, i didn't read carefully enough

Answer (score -1):

```
var i = 1;
var execute = function() {
    $('#li_' + i).removeClass("active");
    $('#a_' + i).removeClass("active");

    i++;
    if(i > 3) {
        i = 1;
    }

    $('#li_' + i).addClass("active");
    $('#a_' + i).addClass("active");
}
```

then

```
setTimeout(execute, 1000)
```

or

```
setInterval(execute, 1000);
```

also, add an id attribute to you HTML tags

```
<li id="li_0">
<a id="a_0">
```

Comment: @Mohakumar oh, sorry, add an id attriibute to the list items.  I'll update the answer

Comment: its working fine but one issue. class is adding but tab content is not active. I have used trigger click but its not working. below is my code,    ' $('#a_' + i).trigger("click");'

Comment: i think it's jsut $(element).click().. if not let me know.  also, please accept the answer if it works, no idea why people downvote working code